# Magento multistore random redirect

Tags: .htaccess, magento, redirect

We have just built a new webstore for Grayle (www.grayle.com) in Magento 1.8.1. The webshop consists of multiple stores (including one for another company).

After switching hosting our online websites finally worked. www.grayle.com -> redirects to www.grayle.nl (as it should). www.eviax.nl -> has it's own website.

**Now the problem:**
At first when we went to www.eviax.nl, we got to www.eviax.nl, then at random someone else tried and got redirected to www.grayle.nl. About 10 minutes later we tried the same thing, we got back at eviax.nl.

What is the problem here? Is it a cache problem in our Magento set-up? Or a problem at the hosts server? Maybe there's something stuck at our provider?

**Edit:**
My colleague enabled cache cleaning in Magento. This resulted in not being redirected, but now we are not able to update/edit static blocks and the catalogue view in the back-end stopped to work.

**Edit:**
This has been solved, the "cache cleaning" script somehow blocks all edits.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localised to one problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a redirection loop. Try to use a cookie to se the redirection once.

Comment: Can a redirection loop be random?